# Fail to run Spark job when using globStatus and Google Cloud Storage bucket as input

Tags: hadoop, google-cloud-storage, apache-spark, google-hadoop

i am using Spark 1.1.
I have a Spark job that seeks for a certain pattern of folders only under a bucket (i.e. folders that start with...), and should process only those. I achieve this by doing the following:

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration(true));
FileStatus[] statusArr = fs.globStatus(new Path(inputPath));
List<FileStatus> statusList = Arrays.asList(statusArr);

List<String> pathsStr = convertFileStatusToPath(statusList);

JavaRDD<String> paths = sc.parallelize(pathsStr);
```

However, when running this job on a Google Cloud Storage path:  gs://rsync-1/2014_07_31* (using the latest google cloud storage connector 1.2.9), I get the following error:

```
4/10/13 10:28:38 INFO slf4j.Slf4jLogger: Slf4jLogger started    
14/10/13 10:28:38 INFO util.Utils: Successfully started service 'Driver' on port 60379.    
14/10/13 10:28:38 INFO worker.WorkerWatcher: Connecting to worker akka.tcp://sparkWorker@hadoop-w-9.c.taboola-qa-01.internal:45212/user/Worker    
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)    
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)    
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)    
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)    
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper$.main(DriverWrapper.scala:40)    
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.DriverWrapper.main(DriverWrapper.scala)    
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong bucket: rsync-1, in path: gs://rsync-1/2014_07_31*, expected bucket: hadoop-config    
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.checkPath(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:100)    
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.makeQualified(FileSystem.java:294)    
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.makeQualified(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:457)    
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.getGcsPath(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:163)    
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.globStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1052)    
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.globStatus(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:1027)    
    at com.doit.customer.dataconverter.Phase0.main(Phase0.java:578)    
... 6 more
```

When I ran this job on a local folder, everything worked fine.

hadoop-config is a bucket I use for deploying the Spark cluster on Google Compute Engine (using bdutil 0.35.2 tool)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Instead of using:

```
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(new Configuration(true));
    FileStatus[] statusArr = fs.globStatus(new Path(inputPath));
    List<FileStatus> statusList = Arrays.asList(statusArr);
```

you need to do

```
    Path inputPathObj = new Path(inputPath);
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(inputPathObj.toUri(), new Configuration(true));
    FileStatus[] statusArr = fs.globStatus(inputPathObj);
    List<FileStatus> statusList = Arrays.asList(statusArr);
```

because in Hadoop, FileSystem instances are shared based on the `scheme` and `authority` component of the URI (and potentially user-group information in more advanced settings), and such instances are not interchangeable between schemes and authorities.

**Long Answer**

This has to do with the distinction between the `hostname` and `path` components of a `URI` in *[scheme]://[authority]/[path]*, which may be more obvious in the HDFS use case, but is also applicable to GCS. Basically, there are several `get` methods in org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem, and the most applicable ones here are:

```
public static FileSystem get(Configuration conf)
```

and

```
public static FileSystem get(URI uri, Configuration conf)
```

The former actually just calls the latter with:

```
    return get(getDefaultUri(conf), conf);
```

where `getDefaultUri(conf)` is defined by `fs.default.name` or `fs.defaultFS`. The second consideration is that FileSystems with different `hosthname` or `authority` components are considered to be inherently different filesystems; in the HDFS case, this makes sense, as:

```
    FileSystem.get("hdfs://foo-cluster-namenode/", conf);
    FileSystem.get("hdfs://bar-cluster-namenode/", conf);
```

each point at potentially completely different filesystem instances, on separate clusters, allowing the same pathnames to be used on the two separate HDFS instances to refer to separate storage namespaces. Though less transparent in terms of "hostnames" of machines, the `bucket` in GCS indeed takes the role as the `authority` component of a GCE URI--in Hadoop, this means `FileSystem.get` literally returns the same cached Java FileSystem object when the `bucket` is the same, but different instances for different buckets. Just as you can't create an HDFS instance and point it at a different authority:

```
    // Can't mix authorities!
    FileSystem.get("hdfs://foo/", conf).listStatus(new Path("hdfs://bar/"));
```

when you called `FileSystem.get(conf)` you effectively got a cached instance pointed at `gs://hadoop-config/`, and then used that to try to list `gs://rsync-1`.

Instead, at the time you know the Path you want to operate on, that should be the time you fetch a FileSystem instance:

```
    FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(myPath.toUri(), new Configuration(true));
    fs.globStatus(myPath);
```